# How to fix a recursive Flood Fill segmentation error?

Tags: c++, c, sdl-2

Hi i'm making a simple paint program to learn sdl and C, i'm getting a segmentation error when i run my code, i think it's because it's trying to fill a pixel that's outside of the window, but i'm not sure how to stop this from happening.
Is there a way to stop the recursion from accessing outside of the window?
here's the code: sorry about how messy it is.

```
void floodfill(SDL_Surface *canvas,int SCREEN_WIDTH, int SCREEN_HEIGHT, int x, int y, int boundingX, int boundingY, Uint32 src, Uint32 fillcolour)
{

Uint32 clickedColour = getPixel(canvas, x, y);
Uint32 boundingColour = getPixel(canvas, boundingX, boundingY); //make sure you are not exceeding the limits of the window.

printf("floodfill Inside\n");
printf("X&Y co-ords %d,%d\n",x,y);

if (src==fillcolour)
    return;

if (x <= 0 || x <= SCREEN_WIDTH || y <= 0  || y <= SCREEN_HEIGHT)
{
    printf("saying things!\n");
    return;
}

printf("%d,%d\n",x,y);

if (fillcolour != clickedColour)
    putPixel(canvas, x, y, fillcolour);

if (clickedColour !=boundingColour)
    return;

if ((x>=0 && x<SCREEN_WIDTH) && (y>=0 && y<SCREEN_HEIGHT))
{
    putPixel(canvas, x, y, fillcolour);
    printf("put Pixel x=%d and y=%d\n", x, y);
}

floodfill(canvas,SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, x, y+1, x, y+2, src, fillcolour);
floodfill(canvas,SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, x, y, x+2, y, src, fillcolour);
floodfill(canvas,SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, x, y, x, y+2, src, fillcolour);
floodfill(canvas,SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, x+1, y, x+2, y, src, fillcolour);
```

}

Comment: surely if you think you're going outside the draw space, you should put some checks at the beginning of the function to make sure you're within the right area?

Comment: What is the last printed line of output?

Comment: The condition if(x <= 0 || x <= SCREEN_WIDTH) doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Hi Roman, it runs printf outside of the function and the i get the segmentation fault

Comment: What Malcolm said. You have some backwards comparison operators, so you will go off screen, leading to infinite recursion, which could be the actual source of the crash.  And as Chris said, that check should happen before you do stuff with the off-screen coords. Fix the check, and do it first. (Also, you are doing weird stuff with the bounding color which will make this probably not work correctly, but that won't make it crash.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any recursively implemented flood-fill will crash with a segfault on sufficiently large input:

It traverses the pixels in a depth-first manner, meaning that the amount of recursive calls grows linear with the size of the area that is flood-filled. As pixels are small, stack frames large by comparison, and stack space limited (typically around single digit amounts of mebibytes), even small images will result in the stack space to be exhausted, and the process to crash with a segfault.

As such, the only way you can safely avoid this is to reimplement your algorithm so that it uses a loop instead of recursive calls.
There are two variants of this:

1. Iterative implementation of depth-first algorithm with an explicit stack. This allows for much deeper "recursion" as the buffer for the explicit stack may be larger than the call stack, and as you will typically push less data onto the stack for each level of recursion.
2. Use a breadth-first algorithm. This may be more space efficient as the front that is moved across the image will tend to be smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with SDL, however at the very least your boundary checking does not look correct. A generic C/C++ flood test algorithm implementation using recursion could look like:

```
// Dimentions for screen to paint, in this case 10x10 matrix
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 10
#define SCREEN_WIDTH  10

void floodFillTest(int x, int y, int old_color, int new_color, int matrix[][SCREEN_HEIGHT])
{
    // Check boundaries
    if (x < 0 || x >= SCREEN_WIDTH || y < 0 || y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        return;

    // Check color to fill boundaries
    if (matrix[x][y] != old_color)
        return;

    // Replace old color at (x, y)
    matrix[x][y] = new_color;

    floodFillTest(x+1, y, old_color, new_color, matrix);  // Recur east
    floodFillTest(x-1, y, old_color, new_color, matrix);  // Recur west
    floodFillTest(x, y+1, old_color, new_color, matrix);  // Recur south
    floodFillTest(x, y-1, old_color, new_color, matrix);  // Recur north
}
```